# Is Aufenthaltstitel binded to anmeldung?

Tags: germany

Suppose I register at an apartment, and use the documents to register for an Aufenthaltstitel. Then, later I change apartments. Would I have to inform city office which issued my aufenthaltstitel?

Comment: I don't know, but in any case you need to inform the *Meldebehörde* (Germans do too).